# I wish to set MAVEN_HOME in the "System Variables" using cmd -> run as administrator

Tags: batch-file, cmd, path, environment-variables

I am trying to set the MAVEN_HOME environment variable using the setx command but in order to set it as a "System variable" and not the "User variable". In order to do this, I have to use -m with setx. Also, I wish to set MAVEN_HOME path as the current directory path in which the batch file is being run. I do this by

```
setx -m MAVEN_HOME "%cd%\apache-maven-3.6.1"
```

If I dont use -m then it sets the Env_variable as a user variable and if I use -m and run it as administrator then it does not pick the current directory path which is "C:\Users\nitin\Desktop\KristomInstall\apache-maven-3.6.1" using %cd%. Instead it picks

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\
```

as the path using %cd%.

What I need is to use -m and run it as administrator along with a way to get the current location of the batch file I am running(as I was trying to do it using %cd%)

```
setx -m MAVEN_HOME "%cd%\apache-maven-3.6.1"
```

so I can distribute this batch file to other systems without manually adding the path to set MAVEN_HOME.

Comment: If you're running this from a [tag:batch-file], what happens if you use `"%~dp0apache-maven-3.6.1"` instead of `"%cd%\apache-maven-3.6.1"`?

Comment: yes, it sets the correct path that I was trying to achieve. Thanks, You might want to put it as an answer so I can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question does not mention it, but the behavior suggests you're running this from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file).

The first thing to note is that `SetX` with `/m` writes the variable to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` in the registry. That is a protected location which requires that your script is `Run as administrator`. When that happens the current directory is usually set to `C:\WINDOWS\System32`, as you have observed.

To cater for this, when your script uses relative paths, you should either change directory, at the outset, to the `d`rive and `p`ath of the running script,

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D "%~dp0"

SetX MAVEN_HOME "%CD%\apache-maven-3.6.1" /m
```

or replace the `%CD%` variable with the `d`rive and `p`ath of the running script.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetX MAVEN_HOME "%~dp0apache-maven-3.6.1" /m
```

*Please remember that the variable you have set will only take effect when a new command window is opened.*