# How do I resolve visibility issue when I set MAVEN_HOME in the “System Variables” "Path" using cmd

Tags: maven, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I am trying to set the MAVEN_HOME environment variable using a batch file (running as administrator) by the command:

```
setx -m MAVEN_HOME "%~dp0apache-maven-3.6.1"
```

and adding '%MAVEN_HOME%\bin' in the "System Variables" -> "Path" using the command:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /d "%Path%;%%MAVEN_HOME%%\bin" /f
```

The issue is that after executing this batch file, the variables are set at their respective locations but it still says:

```
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

UNLESS I go to the Environment variables-> System Variables->Path and just click Ok to close the window.

I have checked the path:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

and it does update the "Path" with `%MAVEN_HOME\bin%`
I have read this in other answers that restarting the system will make the recently set variables visible to other programs but strangely enough, restarting the system also does not resolve it.

I have read about broadcasting the change in environment variables by something like this:

```
SendMessage (HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)"Environment");
```

but I am not sure if it is required when we are directly editing the registry. Also, If it is suggested to help, I don't know how to use the above command in a batch file. I have tried putting it directly like that but it says

```
'SendMessage' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

If you suspect that it is because I am using setx to set "MAVEN_HOME" and by the time I try to set it in "Path" it won't be visible to it, I also tried this and also it sets the correct path but unless I go to  Environment variables-> System Variables->Path and click ok to close the window--it does not work.

```
setx -m MAVEN_HOME "%~dp0apache-maven-3.6.1"
set tempVar="%~dp0apache-maven-3.6.1"
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /d "%Path%;%tempVar%\bin" /f
```

Along with the solution to the above issue, I also wish to know Why even restarting the system also does not make it work. It must have updated the environment variables by then.

Comment: I believe the running batch file does not recognise these changes -- try something like `echo/%PATH%& pause` before trying to execute `mvn`...

Comment: this is strange. echo %Path% does not display the changes I have made in the registry, but the 'edit environment variable' window for 'Path' shows it is there. Even if this batch file completes the execution and I try to execute mvn in another batch file(or even echo %Path% in separate batch file doesn't show it), it gives the error.

Comment: The variable created using `SetX` will not be available in the same `cmd.exe` instance, and must be executed when 'Run as administrator'. Also, why are you using `Reg.exe` to add to the `%PATH%` variable, as well as `SetX`. Also you should learn to use the recommended syntax when setting variables, specifically `Set "tempVar=%~dp0apache-maven-3.6.1"`. It is also very important that you understand the `%PATH%` variable is a concatenated list from both the User and System environments, do not add the concatenated list to HKLM, _(system environment)_, or you will see multiple duplicates there.

Comment: I have also tried creating a variable(tempVar) using 'Set' so that it is available in the same cmd.exe and I am executing it as 'Run as Administrator'. I am directly adding it to the registry because it was suggested in many answers as the best practice. I am using '%~dp0' as it comes from my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57596107/i-wish-to-set-maven-home-in-the-system-variables-using-cmd-run-as-administr. I have experienced that it always 'replaces' in the HKLM list and do not append to it. I am using 'SetX' because I wish to set the variables permanently.

Comment: @NitinNanda, I did not tell you that `Reg Add` appends, I told you that `%PATH%` is a listing of the variables found under both environments, HKLM, _(System)_, and HKCU, _(User)_. What you are doing is adding the content of HKCU, the content of HKLM, and your new path as one string to HKLM. Please take a look at the entire value of your `%PATH%` variable, which will now hold duplicates of any locations that were listed under User too. You can do that by entering `path` at the Command Prompt, `cmd.exe`. Feel free to include its content, in your question too if you believe it will help us!

Comment: What you should be doing, were you to add via the registry, is saving the string data from `Reg Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /V Path` to a temporary variable, via a [tag:for-loop], then `Reg Add`ing it back in with your new location prepended or appended.